# Does GMPY2 (or GMP) have a pow() function?

Tags: python, gmp, gmpy

GMPY2 (or GMP) has a `powmod` function but I can't find anything for regular exponentiation aside from python's native `pow`. Does a function like this exist for `mpz` integers?

Comment: https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mpz.html powmod?

Comment: Did you try `x ** y`? If anything works, it'd probably be that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use Python's standard `pow()` function or the exponentiation `**` operator. GMPY2's `mpz` type overloads all the standard special methods so you should just be able to use standard Python commands.

For example:

```
>>> from gmpy2 import mpz
>>> pow(mpz(3),7)
mpz(2187)
>>> pow(mpz(3),7,13)
mpz(3)
>>> mpz(3)**7
mpz(2187)
>>>
```

The same holds true for divmod(), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Some performance information:

gmpy2 pow is twice as fast as python's pow, even when factoring in construction:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(98765, 10)', number=100000)
0.048412954514788
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(gmpy2.mpz(98765), 10)', number=100000, setup='import gmpy2')
0.024286470230094892
```

You *can* use the built-in `pow(x,y,modulus)` on an mpz, but using powmod instead is a about 10% faster.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(gmpy2.mpz(987654321),1000,100003)', 
number=100000, setup='import gmpy2')
0.057212181510976734
>>> timeit.timeit('gmpy2.powmod(987654321,1000,100003)', 
number=100000, setup='import gmpy2')
0.04513445007546579
>>> timeit.timeit('pow(987654321,1000,100003)', 
number=100000, setup='import gmpy2')
0.15511784474188062
```

The gmpy2 version is much faster than the native python with a modulus (sometimes as much as 10 times faster).  Using powmod is only marginally faster than using pow/mpz, because of the construction time of the mpz.

If you already have an mpz, powmod and pow are aboslutely equivalent.

Comment: Seems that sometimes `powmod` could be even slower than just `mpz(a) ** mpz(b)`. What the reason could it be for that behavior?

Comment: `gmpy2.powmod(a, b, c)` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Sure it does](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html).

> `void mpz_pow_ui (mpz_t rop, const mpz_t base, unsigned long int exp)`
> `void mpz_ui_pow_ui (mpz_t rop, unsigned long int base, unsigned long int exp)`
>
> Set rop to base raised to exp. The case 0^0 yields 1.

There is of course no `mpz_pow(...)` which would take two `mpz_t` input arguments. The reason for that is, if memory serves, because `unsigned long` is thought to be sufficient whereas an `mpz_t e, b` for `b^e` might very easily get out of proportion in terms of memory requirements. I can't seem to find the mailing list post that makes the claim but when I do I'll post the reference.

---

Edit: I can't seem to find a pure `pow` function without modular arithmetic for Python, but it may be a case of me not looking hard enough. I did however see an `sqrt` function which means you can [implement your own `pow`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) (also [this](http://www.programminglogic.com/fast-exponentiation-algorithms/)).

Comment: Hm, does this exist in GMPY2?